# In the Clark Wilson models, why can't the TPs be executed in parallel?

Tags: integrity

I am studying the Clark-Wilson model, I can't exactly understand why the TPs must be executed in serial, is there a way to execute them in parallel?
What would happen if I did execute them in parallel?

Thanks a lot

-- AscaL

Comment: Because executing things in parallel while keeping things transactionally consistent is ridiculously difficult to do?

Comment: Is it difficult or not possible? Does it violate any rule in the model? Thanks :)

Comment: Well, its not impossible but really difficult outside the scope of security models (e.g. from the dev perspective), so I was simply thinking it might be a possible reason why within the scope of a security model.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to execute in parallel in Clark-Wilson because there is no standardized rule for how to handle concurrent access to the same data.  This is a common problem with databases.  For example, what do you do if thread A wants to read data thread B is changing?  Reading over information on database isolation may clarify this for you.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems) is a pretty good resource.